# How to choose which field to display in ng-tags-input autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-tags-input

from documentation:

```
<tags-input>
  <auto-complete
    source="{expression}"
  >
  </auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

The result of the expression must be a promise that eventually resolves to an array of objects.

```
$scope.loadSuperheroes = function(query) {
// An arrays of strings here will also be converted into an
// array of objects
return $http.get('superheroes.json');
};
```

But I have already have an array of objects in $scope. But with a different structure:

```
$scope.superheroes = [{"id":1, "name":"Batman"}, {"id":2, "name":"Superman"}]
```

How to say in html to use list from $scope.superheroes.name ?

Answer (score 4):

You can change the property used to display the tag text by setting the `displayProperty` property:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" display-property="name"></tags-input>
```

That property will also be used by the `autocomplete` directive to display the returned suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the docs : http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/gettingstarted

NgTagsInput can perform autocomplete on an array of basic items (I asked it on GitHub to the creator of that directive months ago).

So I'll think you will have :

1. to **reconstruct your array of objects to something like this** : `[{ text: 'Tag1' }, { text: 'Tag2' }, { text: 'Tag3' }]`
2. Then, **you must use the $query as parameter of your loadSuperheroes()** method (as $query is the text that is being typed.

So, the HTML :

```
<tags-input ng-model="filteredsuperheroes">
 <auto-complete
    source="loadSuperheroes($query)"
  >
  </auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

Then, the JS (Angular) part :

```
$scope.filteredsuperheroes = [];
angular.forEach(superheroes, function(superhero) {
  var newEntry = {};
  newEntry['text'] = superhero.name;
  $scope.filteredsuperheroes.push(newEntry);
});
$scope.loadSuperheroes = function(query) {
   return $http.get('/filteredsuperheroes?query=' + query);
 };
```

Provide a live example, so I'll could test this :) I'm not sure that will work, but you should easily understand what I mean :)

Comment: I understand what you mean. But I was looking the way not to create an additional $scope.filteredsuperheroes. Just to use existing $scope.superheroes

Comment: Ok, is there any reason for that ?

Comment: :-) no reason - just looking for the best way

Comment: I think the best way is to make another array with filtered results. So you keep original array and a filtered array you'll surely need later.

Answer (score 1):

The autocomplete's **source attribute** needs a **promise**, so if you want to use an already existing array of objects you'll have to return a promise that resolves to it:

```
  $scope.superheroes = [{"id":1, "name":"Batman"}, {"id":2, "name":"Superman"}];

  $scope.loadTags = function(query) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve($scope.superheroes);
    return deferred.promise;
  };
```

and, as your displayed property name is not **text** (default by tagsInput), you need to specify  it by adding the attribute **display-property="name"** to tags-input element:

```
<tags-input ng-model="superheroesModel" display-property="name" add-on-paste="true">
      <auto-complete min-length="1" source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

I forked a simple autocomplete example from [ngTagsInput Demo Page](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos) and made these changes. Check it out these changes [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PVtrIM7x7vTF1pLk1aWj?).